# html5 audio mp3 path not working on IE9

Tags: html, audio, internet-explorer-9, mp3, virtualhost

I'm a webmaster and I'm managing multiple website in a single server. I used "virtualhost" to dispatch each website url to the right folder under arn.ae.

So the main url is arn.ae which is the root of my server and radioshoma934.ae is a sub website pointing to a subdirectory called shoma.

In IE9, I discovered that when I use the subwebsite url to point to my audio like this:

```
<audio controls="controls">
<source src="http://radioshoma934.ae/vincent.mp3"  type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

--->The audio is not loaded but if I'm using a full path like this :

```
<audio controls="controls">
<source src="http://arn.ae/shoma/vincent.mp3"  type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

---> It works.

Any body know what configuration is needed in my server to make my subwebsite url working?

Answer (score 0):

It is because **src="http://arn.ae/shoma/vincent.mp3"** is the root address of your server It is the exact location of the file. The First one  **src="http://radioshoma934.ae/vincent.mp3"** is pointing to arn.ae/shoma/. The src tag requires the direct link to the media on the server. and the root url arn.ae/shoma/* is the root path.

you can try doing src="/shoma/vincent.mp3" a relative link.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks mate for your reply. I'm actually trying to make the user pickup a picture from a media library and by default the paths are pointing to http://radioshoma934.ae/ not http://arn.ae/shoma/. Is there any other alternatives as relative paths are not working unfortunately.